# Error with gps android

Tags: android, locationmanager

I have a GPS error in my app when I am trying to get my current location, by gps or by network

```
private static LocationManager lm;
private static LocationListener locationListener;
private static Location posicion;   
private double latitud;
private double longitud;

posicion = ObtenPosicion();       
        latitud = posicion.getLatitude();
        longitud= posicion.getLongitude();

        //Me centro en el mapa
        final GeoPoint yo = new GeoPoint((int)(latitud),(int)(longitud));   

 public Location ObtenPosicion(){
     if (lm == null)
        {
            lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

            locationListener = new LocListener();

            if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            {
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                    LOCATION_UPDATE_TIME, 
                    LOCATION_UPDATE_DISTANCE, 
                    locationListener);

                posicion = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            }

            if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
            {
                        lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
                        LOCATION_UPDATE_TIME, 
                        LOCATION_UPDATE_DISTANCE,  
                        locationListener);

                posicion = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            }
        }
        return posicion;
    }



 private class LocListener implements LocationListener 
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
           posicion.set(loc);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
            Bundle extras) {
        }


    }  

    public static Location getCurrentLocation ()
    {
        return posicion;
    }

    public void stopLocationListening ()
    {
        if (lm != null)
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);

    }
```

The error is a nullpointerexception in a line :

```
12-06 17:04:25.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4744): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 17:04:25.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):     at com.rbrlnx.lugares.editarLugar$LocListener.onLocationChanged(editarLugar.java:215)
```

I tried with a different codes  but its me impossible..

Comment: If this is your real code than try to initialize the "posicion" object in your onCreate method not in the Class body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with the fact that you did not allocate a 'posicio' object.  You simply declared it as static.  So, when you get the callback from the system in the onLocationChanged callback you try to use a null object.

In your onCreate method, you need to allocate and initialize the posicion with:

```
posicion = new Location();
```

Answer (score 0):

The posicion variable is null here.... Initialize it try any/both of the two

In `onCreate()` method, initialize posicion with a default value. And/or than call `ObtenPosicion()` at appropriate place with try/catch if necessary